# Rounding corners of parallelogram made from clip-path CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

I need to create a parallelogram with rounded corners. I'm using clip-path, but haven't been able to round the corners so far. Here's my code, any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

```css
.parallelogram {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 5%, 80% 100%, 0 95%);
    background-color: #f3f5ff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class= parallelogram></div>
```